# How can I create a architecture that allows many clients to use a website with each having different features?

Tags: database-design, web-applications, configuration, coldfusion

I've inherited a monster of an application. It's a website that is used by many clients for order processing. It's old, antiquated, and needs some serious updating. The hardest part about it is that it was originally created with one type of client in mind, and then, as new clients were added, the code was bastardized with hundreds of IF statements that basically turn on or off features for each client. Imagine something like this (written in ColdFusion):

```
<cfif clientId EQ "MIKE">
    <a href="cart1.cfm">Shopping Cart</a>
<cfelseif clientId EQ "JOE">
    <a href="cart2.cfm">Shopping Cart</a>
<cfelseif clientId EQ "BILL"
    OR clientId EQ "JILL"
    OR clientId EQ "RAY">
    <a href="cart3.cfm">Shopping Cart</a>
<cfelse>
    <a href="cart.cfm">Shopping Cart</a>
</cfif>
```

And the above is a nice CLEAN version of what I'm dealing with all over the website.

So, I'm trying to re-factor the website to allow for easier client-specific configurations - basically giving or hiding features for each client.

I started with what I thought was a simple, clean solution, but I'm afraid it might become a bear to maintain.

Basically, I'm going to give each client a directory off the web-root where their files are stored - perhaps documents used on the website, etc.. This directory would be something like `C:\clients\MIKE\`. In this directory, I store an xml file - let's call it config.xml. The first config.xml file I created has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <cart>
        <url>cart1.cfm</url>
    </cart>
</root>
```

So, for every page request, I look for the xml. If it exists, I copy each value into a property of a `Client` class instance:

```
<cfcomponent
    hint="Represents configurable per-Client settings stored in a local Xml file">
    <cfscript>
        VARIABLES.CartLink = "";
    </cfscript>

    <cffunction name="init" return="Client" output="false">
        <cfargument name="clientId" type="String" required="true" hint="i.e. 'MIKE'"/>

        <cfscript>
            var _clientXml = XmlNew();

            THIS = setClientId(ARGUMENTS.clientId);

            _clientXml = read();

            if  (   StructKeyExists(_clientXml.XmlRoot, "cart")
                &&  StructKeyExists(_clientXml.XmlRoot["cart"], "url")
                )
                setCartLink(_clientXml.XmlRoot["cart"]["url"].XmlText);

            return THIS;
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="getCartLink" returntype="String" output="false">
        <cfreturn VARIABLES.CartLink />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="setCartLink" returntype="Void" output="false">
        <cfargument name="cartLink" type="String" required="true" />

        <cfset VARIABLES.CartLink = Trim(ARGUMENTS.cartLink) />
    </cffunction>

    <cfscript>
        function getXmlFilePath() {
            return APPLICATION.ClientFilePath
                & "\" & getClientId() & "\config.xml";
        }
    </cfscript>

    <cffunction name="read" access="public" output="false" returntype="xml">
        <cfscript>
            var _clientXml = XmlNew();
            var _fileContents = "";

            _clientXml.XmlRoot = XmlElemNew(_clientXml, "root");

            if  (FileExists(getXmlFilePath()))
                _fileContents = FileRead(getXmlFilePath());

            if  (IsXml(_fileContents))
                _clientXml = XmlParse(_fileContents);

            return _clientXml;
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Using the sample xml above, when a user is logged in under the "MIKE" client, the Client instance in the REQUEST scope will have a value of "cart1.cfm" for the property `cartLink`.

Now I can simply look for that value and use it to populate the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#REQUEST.Client.getCartLink()#">Shopping Cart</a>
```

My goal is to keep the code clean and avoid hundreds of IF statements all over the place that need to be edited.

But, as I look at this design now, I realize this may become even more of a maintenance nightmare. The website currently has about 30-40 clients. So, right now, I'll need to maintain 30-40 xml files, with any number of nodes for each configuration property. In addition, any time a new feature is added, I'll have to update the Client Class with new getter/setter methods for the new property(ies).

I don't want to make this worse. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: rather than use XML I would store the information in a database. That would make maintaining the application easier in my opinion. Then you could create a form to add/update a client's information.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I don't know ColdFusion, so I can't give you code.

However, the problem you're describing is generally known as "multi-tennant" architecture. It's not unusual for applications to go through the process you describe, hacking these features in retrospectively; it rarely ends well! You may get some joy googling the term, though.

In my experience, you have to chose where you want the complexity to live - currently, it lives in the code, and that's the worst place for it to live. Complex code is harder to maintain, contains more bugs, is harder to change/extend, and makes developers angry.

Managing the complexity as data/configuration is a far, far better way - it reduces the complexity of your codebase dramatically, and is generally easier to manage. You've taken the first step on this road, but I'd refine it a little bit.

Firstly, I'd introduce the concept of "[convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)". So, in the cart example you use, I'd consider naming all variable elements in the solution with the client ID. So instead of "cart3.cfm", it would be "cartMike.cfm". This should reduce the amount of XML munging dramatically.

Secondly, you probably want to introduce the concept of defaults. In most of these cases, 80% of the settings are common across clients, with only 20% requiring client-specific settings. Rather than having to manage all those settings, introduce defaults; if there is no client-specific default, use the one in the default file.

Thirdly, you may want to introduce client types - gold/silver/bronze, free/SME/corporate, whatever. This would require creating default configurations for each of those client types, but may increase the hit rate on your default configuration files.

Finally, you need to consider the application lifecycle - what should the provisioning process be for a new client? Is it primarily a technical task? In that case, I'd continue to use XML files, as they can easily be managed in version control. If it's more a "business" task, you want to wrap it into a more user-friendly process, but you then need to be able to validate the configuration. For instance, if the configuration setting for "cart" is "/Mike/cart.cfm", you need to make sure that file actually exists. You probably also need versioning and a mechanism for moving from developer to test to production environments.

Comment: I've started some of what you're talking about by creating a "sub-application" for some clients who have a lot of customization - /wwwroot/clients/MIKE/... and /wwwroot/clients/BILL/...

Answer (score 1):

I would store client configuration settings in a database. That will make it easier to change settings and also allow them to change settings if they want to choose a different configuration (that may not be the case now but plan ahead). Imagine having different tiers of features each costing a different amount. Allow the customer to maintain their own account and pay accordingly.  I know that's beyond the scope of your question but just an example of how you could address a changing requirement.

Usually I see site configurations stored in a session scope structure for that user after it is pulled from a database after they log in or visit a certain portion of the site.

```
session.userInfo.configurations.cart = cart1.cfm
session.userInfo.configurations.paymentMethod = PayPal
session.userInfo.configurations.maxSubCatLevels = 2
etc.
```

Comment: So, what kind of database setup would work? One table with two columns - one for the Setting and one for the Value? This is the only way this could be maintainable for adding new features at will.

Comment: at the very minimum you would also need to know what configuration you're after.  setting, value, config  "cart", "cart1.cfm", "mike"

Answer (score 1):

I would rather have the data stored in the DB than XML files.  It'll be easier to update (you could build a CMS to do this yourself) than loads of files.

I'd then want to store all that as a big struct, like:

```
stuClient = {
  cart_url = "cart1.cfm",
  other_url = "other2.cfm",
  ...
}
```

I'd also rather store the whole thing in session scope, so you don't have to requery the DB / XML files on every page request.  I'm assuming you're already using session for storing the clientID.

So what you could ultimately do is, in onApplicationStart, get all the data for all clients, once, and store it in application scope.  This part is really optional, because then, in onSessionStart, get just the bit of that data relevant for this client (query-of-query probably, if you've started with it stored in application), and convert it to the struct.

So in your code you simply refer to stuClient.cart_url as required.  And rather than initialise your CFC on each request, I'd do it on each session instead.  Initialised with the data structure.

Then in each page, you could use something like `<a href="#Client.getLink('cart_url')#">`

```
 <cffunction name="getLink" returntype="String" output="false">
        <cfargument name="linktype" type="String" required="true" hint="e.g. 'cart_url'"/>

        <cfreturn VARIABLES.stuClient.CartLink>
    </cffunction>
```

Comment: I've considered this option, and I like it. The only issue with this is having to manually restart the application every time a configuration setting changes. Not a huge deal, but a consideration.

Comment: In which case don't do any query in onApplicationStart, just do it for each client in onSessionStart instead

Answer (score 0):

I will provide an example to what others have explained. The easiest solution here is for you to replace all those conditions with a simple method call for each "setting." This is a tried and true proven technique for dealing with your situation. Even if you aren't using sessions, you can have a number of ways to cache or have the data available without going to the database every time were you to this in a more rudimentary fashion. Below I have application.cfc, settings.cfc, and a template.

```
//In your application.cfc onSessionStart (hopefully you are using sessions)
session.settings = createObject("component", "settings").init(clientID);

//In your settings.cfc 
//saving keystrokes with cfscript style functions
<cfscript>
function init(clientID){
   variables.clientID = arguments.clientID;
   setAllUserSettings();
   return this;
} 

function setAllUserSettings(){
   //query the database for a particular user 
   //you can keep the query in memory or set each row value to something
   //let's say you wanted to use the QoQ method
   variables.settings = qryAllUserSettings();       
}
</cfscript>

<cffunction name="getSetting">
    <cfarguments name="type" />
    //start query of query to get a particular setting
    //for our user
    <cfquery name="qry" dbtype="query">
         select value
         from variables.settings
         where setting = #arguments.type#
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn qry.value />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="qryAllUserSettings">
   <cfset var qry = "" />
   //we'll get every possible setting for this user
   <cfquery name="qry" datasource="dsn">
        select setting,value
        from tblSettings
        where clientID = variables.clientID
   </cfquery>
   <cfreturn qry />
</cffunction>

//In your ColdFusion Template
<a href="#session.settings.getSetting(type="cart")">Shopping Cart</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what has previously been said I would go down the holding the information in the database. ColdFusion ables you to then create independent applications that can utilise the same base code with multiple Application.cfc's or .cfm files, all you need to do is make sure that each file has a unique this.name variable and have it located in a separate client folder. Then on application startup read the clients specific settings and then cache them in application scope.

ColdFusion (specifically the enterprise version) has been designed exactly for this purpose and there is a lot of information online that can help. Have a search around for managing multiple applications and how the application.cfc can help you do this.